# Could someone explain how exactly this predicate is working?

Tags: list, prolog

So I have the following predicate which takes a list of symbols as its first parameter, then outputs this list with all of the duplicates removed:

```
removeDups([], []).
removeDups([H|T], [H|T1]) :-
   subtract(T, [H], T2),
   removeDups(T2, T1).
```

It works as intended but I'm not exactly sure how to make sense of it.

What I've understood so far is:

1. Obviously first the predicate is setup with two empty lists as parameters
2. The Head and Tails of the lists are setup
3. I don't understand what the subtract part is doing, it removes a tail value from the head value? And then stores it in a temporary variable `T2`?
4. Then the temporary value of `T2` is stored into `T1`?

I'm quite confused as to what exactly is going on here so any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate subtract/3 describes a relation where the 3rd argument is the 1st argument without the elements of the 2nd argument, e.g.:

```
   ?- subtract([1,2,3],[1],L).
L = [2,3]
   ?- subtract([1,2,3],[1,2],L).
L = [3]
```

The first rule of removeDups/2 is the base case:

```
removeDups([],[]).
```

You can read it as: *The empty list without duplicates is the empty list*. The second rule is the general case of the relation, where the 1st list is not empty.

```
removeDups([H|T], [H|T1]) :-  % the head of list 1 is in the head of list 2
   subtract(T, [H], T2),      % T2 is the tail of list 1 without H
   removeDups(T2,T1).         % T1 is a duplicate free T2
```

So the goal with subtract/3 describes a list `T2` that contains all elements but `H` of `T`. Since through the recursions the list `T2` becomes shorter and shorter you inevitably end up with the base case `[]`. And that is described by the first rule. Procedurally speaking you need the base case so your predicate can terminate.  However, as pointed out by @repeat, the use of subtract/3 can be problematic if the first two arguments contain free variables. Consider the following examples:

```
   ?- X=1, subtract([1,2,3],[X],L).
L = [2,3],
X = 1
   ?- subtract([1,2,3],[X],L), X=1.
L = [2,3],
X = 1
```

But:

```
   ?- X=2, subtract([1,2,3],[X],L).
L = [1,3],
X = 2
   ?- subtract([1,2,3],[X],L), X=2.
no
```

So it's a good idea to test those arguments for sufficient instantiation as suggested by him in the comments:

```
removeDups([],[]).
removeDups([H|T], [H|T1]) :-
   safe_subtract(T, [H], T2),
   removeDups(T2,T1).

safe_subtract(As,Bs,Xs) :-
   ( ground(As+Bs) ->
     subtract(As,Bs,Xs) ;
     throw(error(instantiation_error,_))).
```

Comment: `subtract/3` is both (potentially) non-monotonic and non-portable.

Comment: Why not replace `subtract(Es,[X],Xs)` by `maplist(dif(X),Es,Xs)` ?

Comment: @repeat: Because in this case the name of the game is *predicate explain* rather than *predicate suggest* ;-) But I agree with you, in the latter case your suggestion with maplist/3 would be the way to go.

Comment: Fair enough. OTOH using something like `safe_subtract(As,Bs,Xs) :- ( ground(As+Bs) -> subtract(As,Bs,Xs) ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) ).` wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @repeat: Point taken. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This procedure states that `removeDups(L,L1)`:

- clause1: should succeed if L and L1 both unify with empty lists
- clause2: `L` and `L1` are both lists with at least one element, the head of each list (`H`) unifies with the head of the other list, then [subtract/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subtract/3) is called with the tail of the list (`T`) from the first argument and a list comprising solely with the head. This procedure will unify the third argument (`T2`) with a list containing the elements of `T` without `H`. Then the recursive call to `removeDups/3` applies the same algorithm to the resulting list (which does not have `H`). The recursive call has at least one element less than the original list `L`. Upon returning from the recursive call T1 should have no duplicates (and `H` won't be in it either). However as the third argument to removeDups is `[H|T1]` the caller will have in the third argument `H` as the head of the third list.